# how to make the straight polyline to arc like bend curve connecting two marker points while showing in google map + flutter

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps, maps, flutter-dependencies

im having a working code where im showing a google map in my android flutter app and im showing 2 marker points connected by a straight polyline.

now instead of that straight line i want to show an arc like bend curve polyline connecting both the markers.

Expected polyline:

[image]

Actual Polyline:

[image]

i searched in all forms, but its still rendering it as a straight line only
how to achieve this requirement.
below is the working code

```
class BookingAlertMap extends StatelessWidget {
  final GeoPoint sourceLoc; // Equipment Location
  final GeoPoint destinationLoc; // Customer Location
  final GeoPoint currentLocation;
  final GeoPoint? operatorLocation;

  BookingAlertMap(
      {required this.sourceLoc,
      required this.destinationLoc,
      required this.currentLocation,
      this.operatorLocation});

  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      child: destinationLoc.latitude == 0.0 ||
              destinationLoc.longitude == 0.0 ||
              sourceLoc.latitude == 0.0 ||
              sourceLoc.longitude == 0.0 ||
              (operatorLocation?.latitude == 0.0 ||
              operatorLocation?.longitude == 0.0)
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : Center(
              child: GoogleMap(
                mapType: MapType.normal,
                initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                  target: _calculateCenter(),
                  zoom: _calculateZoomLevel(),
                ),
                markers: _createMarkers(),
                polylines: _createPolylines(),
                onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                  _controller.complete(controller);
                },
              ),
            ),
    );
  }

  LatLng _calculateCenter() {
    double centerLat = (sourceLoc.latitude + destinationLoc.latitude) / 2;
    double centerLng = (sourceLoc.longitude + destinationLoc.longitude) / 2;

    print("Calculated Center: LatLng($centerLat, $centerLng)");

    return LatLng(centerLat, centerLng);
  }

  double _calculateZoomLevel() {
    const double padding = 0.0; // Adjust padding as needed

    double south = min(sourceLoc.latitude, destinationLoc.latitude);
    double west = min(sourceLoc.longitude, destinationLoc.longitude);
    double north = max(sourceLoc.latitude, destinationLoc.latitude);
    double east = max(sourceLoc.longitude, destinationLoc.longitude);

    double boundsPadding = padding * 2;
    double zoom = 0;

    // Calculate the zoom level based on the bounding box
    double lngDiff = east - west;
    double latDiff = north - south;
    double lngZoom = (lngDiff == 0) ? 0 : (log(360 / lngDiff) / ln2);
    double latZoom = (latDiff == 0) ? 0 : (log(180 / latDiff) / ln2);
    zoom = min(lngZoom, latZoom);

    // Adjust zoom level with padding
    double minZoom =
        min(zoom, 18.0); // You can adjust the maximum zoom level if needed
    print("Calculated Zoom Level: $minZoom");
    return minZoom - (boundsPadding / 2);
  }

Set<Marker> _createMarkers() {
  Set<Marker> markers = {
    Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId('source'),
      position: LatLng(sourceLoc.latitude, sourceLoc.longitude),
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueRed),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'Source Location'),
    ),
    Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId('destination'),
      position: LatLng(destinationLoc.latitude, destinationLoc.longitude),
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueGreen),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'Destination Location'),
    ),
    Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId('current'),
      position: LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude),
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueBlue),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'Current Location'),
    ),
  };

  // Add operatorLocation marker if available
  if (operatorLocation != null) {
    markers.add(
      Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId('operator'),
        position: LatLng(operatorLocation!.latitude, operatorLocation!.longitude),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueOrange),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'Operator Location'),
      ),
    );
  }

  return markers;
}

Set<Polyline> _createPolylines() {
  Set<Polyline> polylines = {
    Polyline(
      polylineId: PolylineId('route'),
      points: [
        LatLng(sourceLoc.latitude, sourceLoc.longitude),
        LatLng(destinationLoc.latitude, destinationLoc.longitude),
      ],
      color: Colors.blue,
      width: 3,
    ),
  };

  // Add polyline connecting sourceLoc and operatorLocation if operatorLocation is available
  if (operatorLocation != null) {
    polylines.add(
      Polyline(
        polylineId: PolylineId('operatorRoute'),
        points: [
          LatLng(sourceLoc.latitude, sourceLoc.longitude),
          LatLng(operatorLocation!.latitude, operatorLocation!.longitude),
        ],
        color: Colors.orange,
        width: 3,
      ),
    );
  }

  return polylines;
}

}
```

Comment: Have u try `round → const JointType` ?